# RedisInsight 1.7.0 for Windows: Failed to execute script entry.prod

Tags: redis

I am using RedisInsight for Windows (redisinsight-win-1.7.0.msi), link download https://d3fyopse48vfpi.cloudfront.net/latest/redisinsight-win.msi   . homepage: https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/

I catch error

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Hi, you could write to redisinsight@redislabs.com for help from the RedisInsight team. Here are the instructions for sharing your log files: https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/ri/using-redisinsight/troubleshooting/#logs

Comment: Exactly same issue here, after using RedisInsight for weeks.
Did you find any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I just ran the RedisInsight exe as **administrator** and the service worked.

Answer (score -1):

had same error after installing it, after restarting pc it worked fine.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.